# How can I change the text of an existing ToolTip control, in a PictureBox in my WinForm application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip, picturebox

I have a winform application which has a dynamic number (based on a database value) of `PictureBoxes`. Each P-Box has a `Tooltip` control.

How can I change the ToolTip Text without having any memory leaks? Right now, I've got the following code, but it's leaking memory => the previous ToolTip controls are not getting GC'd.

BTW, this is a background thread that is trying to update the main UI thread....

```
if (pictureBox == null || !pictureBox.IsHandleCreated) {
    continue;
}

Action setTooltipAndImage = () => {
    var toolTip = new ToolTip();
    GameServer tempGameFile = gameServer;
    toolTip.SetToolTip(pictureBox, string.Format(...));
    pictureBox.Image = Resources.RedButton;
};

if (pictureBox.InvokeRequired) {                        
    pictureBox.Invoke(setTooltipAndImage);
} else {
    setTooltipAndImage();
}
```

As I said - this works but it's leaking.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: +1 to et you back to zero, seems like a totally acceptable question. BTW: what tools are you using to see the ToolTip memory leak?

Comment: I'm using ANTS Memory Profiler. Here's a similar question i asked with screenshots: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225959/how-can-i-debug-this-stackoverflowexception-in-my-winform-application

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't create a new ToolTip each time.  Add a ToolTip to the form using the visual designer, like you would for any other control or component.  Call `toolTip.SetToolTip(...)` on the form's tool tip each time.  The ToolTip will be disposed when the Form is disposed.

Comment: Problem with that is that I don't know how many I need. It's based upon some dynamic data. So i need to make them dynamically.

Comment: You only need one.  One ToolTip component can provide tips for thousands of controls.  When you call `toolTip.SetToolTip(Control, Text)`, it adds the control and text to an internal collection and handles the control's mouse events.  When you hover over a control, the ToolTip component looks up the associated text.  To remove an entry from this collection, call `toolTip.SetToolTip(Control, null)`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you do not need to create a new ToolTip each time, a single ToolTipwill do. There is no issue if you do not know how many ToolTips you want, because if there is only one ToolTip say `toolTip1`, then you can use the following every time you want to change the ToolTip caption and control on some event. **You only need one ToolTip instance per form.**

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(Current_pictureBox, "<tool tip string>");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. > You only need one ToolTip instance per form.
2. `toolTip.SetToolTip(control, caption)` - can use with many control, you can set caption for each control
3. `toolTip.ToolTipTitle` - set tool tip title, the title is one for all control bonded with tool tip

for example :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(button1, "btn1");
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(button2, "btn2");
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(button3, "btn3");
}


private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = textBox1.Text;
}
```

[image]